# Find values of n for which expression is integer

Tags: simplifying-expressions, number-theory, algebra

I have an expression for which I want ot find values of n that will make it an integer. Here is the expression:

```
(n^(3/2) - n)^(1/3)
or
n^(1/2) - n^(1/3)
```

I want to find all positive values of n for which the above expression will be an Integer. Can I do that with Mathematica?

Thanks.

Comment: You can use "Reduce: "Reduce[{b == (n^(3/2) - n)^(1/3), n > 0, b \[Element] Integers}]". This gives an answer using a root object. This is a shorthand for the roots of the enclose polynomial. If you want to transform it to radicals, you give to output to: "ToRadicals"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `InverseFunction`

```
f := Evaluate@InverseFunction[(#^(3/2) - #)^(1/3) &]

a = N[f /@ Range[3]]
```

> {2.1479, 5.73535, 11.3776}

The above values will produce integers, e.g.

```
(#^(3/2) - #)^(1/3) & /@ a
```

> {1., 2., 3.}

Comment: Instead of `f := Evaluate@InverseFunction[...` you could simply write `f = InverseFunction[...`.

Comment: @Roman Ah, yes. With `Set` rather than `SetDelayed`.